# I cannot implement an async function

Tags: node.js, protractor, cucumber

I've started working with protractor-cucumber automation testing (https://github.com/mlev/protractor-cucumber-example), previously in one of my other projects I had no issue implementing async await functions, however, in this case I cannot.

This is my current semi-working (protractor outpust completed for all tasks, however it will not wait at browser.sleep) code:

I have tried nodes async await libary and the following code:

```
    this.get = async function someName(){
            await browser.get('https://translate.google.com/');
        };


     this.Given('The Translate is open', async function (callback) {
            await this.page.get();
            callback();
        }
```

StepsDef:

```
    var chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
var expect = chai.expect;

var TranslateSteps = function() {

    var TranslatePage = require("../pages/translate_page");

    this.World = function MyWorld() {
        this.page = new TranslatePage();
    };

    this.Given('The Translate is open', function (callback) {
        this.page.get();
        callback();
    }
)
    this.Then('I wait $string seconds',  function (string) {
      browser.sleep(string * 10000)
    }

};

    module.exports = TranslateSteps;
```

Page:

```
var TranslatePage = function() {



    this.get = function (){
        browser.get('https://translate.google.com/');
    };
    this.setInputBox = function (value) {
        element(by.className("gt-hl-layer")).sendKeys(value)
        console.log("setInput")
    };
    this.clickLang = function () {
        element(by.className("sl-more tlid-open-source-language-list")).click()
        console.log("clickLang")
    }

};
module.exports = TranslatePage;
```

most of the time I got error code 1 or 100, at times i got no 199.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that you disable promise manager by adding this `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` line in the `protractor.conf.js` file.

1. You don't need to use the `callback` function.

   ```
   this.get = async function() {
       await browser.get('https://translate.google.com/');
   };


   this.Given('The Translate is open', async function() {
       await this.page.get();
   });
   ```
2. As I said above you don't need the `callback` function. Alson the sleep method expects number type instead of the string.

   ```
    var TranslateSteps = function() {

      var TranslatePage = require("../pages/translate_page");

      this.World = function MyWorld() {
      this.page = new TranslatePage();
      };

     this.Given('The Translate is open', async function() {
       await this.page.get();
     });
     this.Then('I wait {num} seconds',  async function(num) {
       await browser.sleep(num * 10000)
     });
    };
   ```
3. Add `async/await`'s.

   ```
   var TranslatePage = function() {

     this.get = async function() {
       await browser.get('https://translate.google.com/');
     };
     this.setInputBox = async function(value) {
       await element(by.className("gt-hl-layer")).sendKeys(value)
       await console.log("setInput")
     };
     this.clickLang = async function() {
       await element(by.className("sl-more tlid-open-source-language-list")).click()
       await console.log("clickLang")
     }

   };

   module.exports = TranslatePage;
   ```

Comment: Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

       this.Then(/^I wait (\d+) seconds$/, function (arg1, callback) {
         // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
         callback(null, 'pending');
       });
           I apologise for the inproper formatting. I tried to use the given code, however, again error 'function accepts a callback and returns a promise'

Comment: Hey @PéterSzabó-tóth.
Which line of code throws an error?

Comment: Helo @Yevhen, It does not show, in the fisrt case(where it says i should use the snippet above). When I try to implement the snippet the snippet throws the error(unction accepts a callback and returns a promise).

Comment: I have managed to get it work, however it has another, probably relating problem, since I did not use async await.
I have managed to get it to work now, however I have trouble delaying functions and not to run all simultaneously,(or I'm guessing that is what is happening) Steps:
`this.When('I enter first value of $first', function (first, callback) {
    this.page.setFirstValue(first);
    callback();
  });
`
Page:
 `this.setFirstValue = function(value) {
    element(by.className('classname')).sendKeys(value);
  };`

Comment: Result:
all tests have passed, however after like some seconds it gives an error that, "classname" is not found, which is true, but it still passes, could you please give me some insight why is this happening?
Also when I write a proper selector, one that does exist (and only one of it), it passes the test, however, it does not actually complete the action so it doesn't write(.sendkeys) or click(.click)

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.When('I enter $string', async function myF(string) {
await this.page.setFirstValue(string);
return true;
});
```

and:

```
this.setFirstValue = async function asd(value) {
await element(by.className('orig tlid-source-text-input goog-textarea')).sendKeys(value);
};
```

works like a charm